# strstr() not working on C

Tags: c, linux, coredump, strstr

I have the code below. The problem is when I run it, It shows me nothing for the search that I've tipped; trying `printf("%s", strstr(tracks[i], search_for))` inside *for*, brings back null, but no problems doing the same with *tracks[i]* and *search_for*. Please help!.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char tracks[][80]={
  "I left my heart in Harvard Med Scholl",
  "Newark, Newark - a wonderful town",
  "Dancing with a Dork",
  "From here to maternity",
  "The girl from Iwo Jima",
};

void find_track(char search_for[]){
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<5; i++){
    if(strstr(tracks[i], search_for)){
      printf("Track %i: '%s'\n", i, tracks[i]);
    }
  }
};

int main(){

  char search_for[80];
  printf("Search for: ");
  fgets(search_for, 80, stdin);
  find_track(search_for);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As we can see in the [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) documentation, if there is a newline at the end of the line, it will be included in the produced string:

> Reads at most count - 1 characters from the given file stream and stores them in str. The produced character string is always NULL-terminated. Parsing stops if end-of-file occurs or a newline character is found, in which case str will contain that newline character.

So in this case, if we input `"Newark"`, then we have:

```
search_for[] = {'N', 'e', 'w', 'a', 'r', 'k', '\n', '\0', ...};
```

You will want to remove that extra newline.

Comment: Thanks! Solved including `strtok(search_for, "\n");`